# Can I boot different operating systems from same external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive, operating-systems

Is it possible to use one external hard drive with multiple operating systems on it so when I go onto the BIOS of my PC and can choose to boot from USB then choose which operating system rom the hard drive I want to boot from.

I would appreciate it if you could include links to videos, posts or blogs that i have not come across that may solve my problem. Also if there is software that does this please could you link to it.

Thanks for any help that you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install 'grub' bootloader on the external hard drive (google for details). Then you can create a menu which appears at boot time and gives you options for booting from different disks/partitions.

Alternatively, when you install a Linux distribution on a parition, it will (on most distributions) give you option for installing grub2 bootloader, which checks for all operating systems on the computer and creates a boot-time menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same techniques with USB hard drives as with USB thumb drives. Check out the YUMI tool here:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/

This Hak5 video demonstrates how to use it:

http://hak5.org/episodes/haktip-4